# Debugger does not stop at breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, double, .net-3.5, breakpoints

Why does Visual Studio not stop at breakpoint in this example?

```
...
string s = "abc";
double d = s.Length; // <----- breakpoint
...
```

**Visual Studio:** 2015

**Target framework:** .NET Framework 3.5

**Configuration:** Debug

[image]

Comment: Usually this happens when you are in Release mode. Check it and clean your solution before starting a new debug session

Comment: Does the entire solution build correctly? So that you are sure you're looking at the same code as has been compiled...? And you're positive it's a debug build?

Comment: It is in debug configuration after solution rebuild. Breakpoint is visible in **Breakpoints** window, but not in **Disassembly**.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. You say that the debugger doesn't stop at the d.ToString() line, but your screen image shows that the debugger DID stop at that line. So what is your issue???

Comment: No, once again. I never nowhere say that debugger doesn't stop at the d.ToString() line. Please, check the question again properly. I'm talking about the line **double d = s.Length; // <----- breakpoint** As you can see, breakpoint is set on this line but debugger doesn't stop at it but only the next one. Pretty much like you can see breakpoints in disassembly view.